# How to enable Push Upgrades for Managed Packages using Patch Organizations

Tags: managed-package, isv, partner, push-upgrade

Is package patching available only for registered partner accounts ? I have freeware created developer account. As I see I can not create this or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without being a partner it won't work at all on a public developer org. You'll get only this:

[image]

So you could sign-up. The basic process shouldn't be too hard.

If you are a partner you have it by default. You think. But it's only a "light version"....

All that patch orgs are used to execute push upgrades. Those push upgrades even for partners come in two flavors: **Push-Minor** and **Push-Major**.

With push-minor you can only change existing components, which is in fact not very helpful for most use cases.

**Probably only with push-major, you can do what you really want**:
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter13/PUSH+Major+Upgrade

To get Push-Major activated you have to either pass the security review or you have to register into the ISV-Programme. I tried this for a free App ( https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5SYEEA3 ) but they refused it. At least in Germany they seem to accept only paid solutions, no free apps, no even freemium models (e.g. one paid package and parallel a less-featured free second package). This is very sad.

I'm trying to find out other options here ( https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41968/push-major-upgrades-before-security-review-possible ) - but nothing so far...

Then finally, if you have passed the review or joined ISV, you can log a case and ask them to activate it.

So an unfortunate, it's not so easy to get a full featured push upgrade process up and running...

Comment: @Rastko : you are welcome. Documentation is not perfect on this and I wasted a lot of time to learn it the hard way. If you or anyone else finds out about how to convince Salesforce to get push-major for free (or freemium) apps in an earlier stage of the development process, please let me know. Maybe we are just talking to the wrong people there. I'm sure that there are also guys who love open source at Salesforce... So I have not given it up completely.